# How to add element in linkedlist without checking any condition of isEmpty() Function in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wanna know that how to add any element in single or double linkedlist without checking `isEmpty()` function

```
bool LinkedList<T>::addAtEnd(T ele) {
    bool bSuccess = false;
    Node<T> * t = new Node<T>;
    t->SetData(ele);      
    if (empty()) {
        t->SetNext(NULL);
        head = t;
        tail = t;
        count++;
        bSuccess = true;
    }
    else {
        t->SetNext(NULL);
        tail->SetNext(t);
        tail = t;
        count++;
        bSuccess = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if tail is null or if head is null instead of the empty() function.

Either one will tell you if the linklist is empty or not.